# partitioning text at nearest pipe at every 2000 characters

Tags: python, string, encoding, substr

I'm currently writing a program that posts messages with a 2,000 character limit. The string I'm using is usually around 10,000 characters. However, the method I'm using to divide it up can divide the string up in the middle of a word - how would I only have it divide at the nearest space (BEFORE) 2k characters?

In my code I need to call API at evey 2000 characters. But input text size is >5000 sometimes.

How ever, the simple substring partitioning devides the text in middle of word. So as it is hindi text, I want to split it at nearest "।" character. I have written this logic for the same. Is it correct?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text = " ( नई दिल्ली केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की है. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ. सीबीआई ने 3 एफआईआर दर्ज की है, जिनमें 111 विमानों की खरीद, विमानों को पट्टे पर देना और एयर इंडिया द्वारा मुनाफे वाले हवाई मार्गों को छोड़ने की जांच शामिल है. गौरतलब है कि मार्च 2007 में तत्कालीन यूपीए सरकार ने सरकारी विमानन कंपनी एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइन्स के विलय को फाइनल मंजूरी दी थी. नई एयरलाइन में दोनों के करीब 120 विमान और 30 हजार से ज्यादा कर्मचारी एक हो गए. हालांकि एयरलाइन के सरकारी स्वरूप में बदलाव नहीं हुआ. अनुमानों के मुताबिक एयर इंडिया पर 52,000 करोड़ रुपये की देनदारी है जिसमें से अकेले ब्याज ही 4,000 करोड़ रुपये सालाना है. बीते पांच सालों में सरकार ने सार्वजनिक क्षेत्र की इस एयरलाइन को 25,000 करोड़ रुपये दिए हैं और 2032 तक इतनी ही रकम और दिए जाने की बात है. इन सभी प्रयासों के बावजूद भी एयर इंडिया को सालाना 3,000 करोड़ रुपये का घाटा हो रहा है. अधिकारियों का मानना है कि कंपनी की मौजूदा हालत के लिए एयर इंडिया-इंडियन एयरलाइंस का विलय भी जिम्मेदार है. )(केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ.केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ.) ( नई दिल्ली केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की है. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ. सीबीआई ने 3 एफआईआर दर्ज की है, जिनमें 111 विमानों की खरीद, विमानों को पट्टे पर देना और एयर इंडिया द्वारा मुनाफे वाले हवाई मार्गों को छोड़ने की जांच शामिल है. गौरतलब है कि मार्च 2007 में तत्कालीन यूपीए सरकार ने सरकारी विमानन कंपनी एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइन्स के विलय को फाइनल मंजूरी दी थी. नई एयरलाइन में दोनों के करीब 120 विमान और 30 हजार से ज्यादा कर्मचारी एक हो गए. हालांकि एयरलाइन के सरकारी स्वरूप में बदलाव नहीं हुआ. अनुमानों के मुताबिक एयर इंडिया पर 52,000 करोड़ रुपये की देनदारी है जिसमें से अकेले ब्याज ही 4,000 करोड़ रुपये सालाना है. बीते पांच सालों में सरकार ने सार्वजनिक क्षेत्र की इस एयरलाइन को 25,000 करोड़ रुपये दिए हैं और 2032 तक इतनी ही रकम और दिए जाने की बात है. इन सभी प्रयासों के बावजूद भी एयर इंडिया को सालाना 3,000 करोड़ रुपये का घाटा हो रहा है. अधिकारियों का मानना है कि कंपनी की मौजूदा हालत के लिए एयर इंडिया-इंडियन एयरलाइंस का विलय भी जिम्मेदार है. )(केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ.केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ.)"
import re
text = re.sub(r"(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)", '। ',text)
text = text.decode("utf-8")

def split_message(message, character_limit=2000):
    messages = []

    while len(message) > character_limit:
        split_index = message[:character_limit].rfind("।".decode("utf-8"))
        if split_index == -1:
            # No । found, just split at the character limit
            split_index = character_limit
        else:
            # Else space is found, split after the space
            split_index += 1
        messages.append(message[:split_index])
        message = message[split_index:] 

    messages.append(message)
    return messages

res = split_message(text)
for val in res:
    print val.encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a `textwrap` module which may help you here. https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html

```
import textwrap

text = " ( नई दिल्ली केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की है. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ. सीबीआई ने 3 एफआईआर दर्ज की है, जिनमें 111 विमानों की खरीद, विमानों को पट्टे पर देना और एयर इंडिया द्वारा मुनाफे वाले हवाई मार्गों को छोड़ने की जांच शामिल है. गौरतलब है कि मार्च 2007 में तत्कालीन यूपीए सरकार ने सरकारी विमानन कंपनी एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइन्स के विलय को फाइनल मंजूरी दी थी. नई एयरलाइन में दोनों के करीब 120 विमान और 30 हजार से ज्यादा कर्मचारी एक हो गए. हालांकि एयरलाइन के सरकारी स्वरूप में बदलाव नहीं हुआ. अनुमानों के मुताबिक एयर इंडिया पर 52,000 करोड़ रुपये की देनदारी है जिसमें से अकेले ब्याज ही 4,000 करोड़ रुपये सालाना है. बीते पांच सालों में सरकार ने सार्वजनिक क्षेत्र की इस एयरलाइन को 25,000 करोड़ रुपये दिए हैं और 2032 तक इतनी ही रकम और दिए जाने की बात है. इन सभी प्रयासों के बावजूद भी एयर इंडिया को सालाना 3,000 करोड़ रुपये का घाटा हो रहा है. अधिकारियों का मानना है कि कंपनी की मौजूदा हालत के लिए एयर इंडिया-इंडियन एयरलाइंस का विलय भी जिम्मेदार है. )(केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ.केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ.) ( नई दिल्ली केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की है. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ. सीबीआई ने 3 एफआईआर दर्ज की है, जिनमें 111 विमानों की खरीद, विमानों को पट्टे पर देना और एयर इंडिया द्वारा मुनाफे वाले हवाई मार्गों को छोड़ने की जांच शामिल है. गौरतलब है कि मार्च 2007 में तत्कालीन यूपीए सरकार ने सरकारी विमानन कंपनी एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइन्स के विलय को फाइनल मंजूरी दी थी. नई एयरलाइन में दोनों के करीब 120 विमान और 30 हजार से ज्यादा कर्मचारी एक हो गए. हालांकि एयरलाइन के सरकारी स्वरूप में बदलाव नहीं हुआ. अनुमानों के मुताबिक एयर इंडिया पर 52,000 करोड़ रुपये की देनदारी है जिसमें से अकेले ब्याज ही 4,000 करोड़ रुपये सालाना है. बीते पांच सालों में सरकार ने सार्वजनिक क्षेत्र की इस एयरलाइन को 25,000 करोड़ रुपये दिए हैं और 2032 तक इतनी ही रकम और दिए जाने की बात है. इन सभी प्रयासों के बावजूद भी एयर इंडिया को सालाना 3,000 करोड़ रुपये का घाटा हो रहा है. अधिकारियों का मानना है कि कंपनी की मौजूदा हालत के लिए एयर इंडिया-इंडियन एयरलाइंस का विलय भी जिम्मेदार है. )(केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ.केंद्रीय जांच ब्यूरो (सीबीआई) ने एयर इंडिया और इंडियन एयरलाइंस के विलय से जुड़े मामलों की पड़ताल के लिए एफआईआर दर्ज की. सीबीआई का आरोप है कि दोनों एयरलाइंस के विलय की वजह से करोड़ों रुपये का नुकसान हुआ.)"

text = text.decode("utf-8")

result = textwrap.wrap(text, width=2000)

for line in result:
    print(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: but it breaks the string in between word also.` [' my name is. khan pathan. so dont. worry.']
>>> res = textwrap.wrap(t, width=5)
>>> res
[' my', 'name', 'is.', 'khan ', 'patha', 'n. so', 'dont.', 'worry', '.']
`

Comment: `textwrap.wrap(text, width=5, break_long_words=False)`

Comment: checked but now length goes out of range `[' my', 'name', 'is.', 'khan', 'pathan.', 'so', 'dont.', 'worry.']`

Comment: Well, yes. If you have a width that's less than a word length, it'll either get split, or be over the width. Those are the only two options. With your width of 2000, though, that won't matter